# Getting List indexed memory locations. Not value locations but List index locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, heap-memory

From what I am aware, Python stores Lists as "arrays" in memory; however, the "array" stores pointers to the PyObject's in the List.

I am using `hex(id(...))` to view the memory addresses of the List and of all the items in the list. But I also want to see the memory location of the "array" positions.

This is my interpreter code so far...

```
>>> def memory_locations_of(value):
        for index, element in enumerate(value):
            print("{: <15}{}\n{: <15}{}\n".format("index[" + str(index) + "] ", hex(id(element)), str(element), hex(id(str(element)))))

>>> a = ["hello", "world", "!", "!"]
>>> a
['hello', 'world', '!', '!']

>>> memory_locations_of(a)
index[0]       0x34b4bc0
hello          0x34b4bc0
index[1]       0x4053dc0
world          0x4053dc0
index[2]       0x3616620
!              0x3616620
index[3]       0x3616620
!              0x3616620

>>> a[0] = "Hello"
>>> a
['Hello', 'world', '!', '!']

>>> memory_locations_of(a)
index[0]       0x406e260
Hello          0x406e260
index[1]       0x4053dc0
world          0x4053dc0
index[2]       0x3616620
!              0x3616620
index[3]       0x3616620
!              0x3616620

>>> hex(id(a))
'0x3f7cc10'
```

The last 2 lines are the closest memory location that I want. That memory location is the location of the actual List. That should also be the location of the actual a[0] position (or very close to it). I also want to get the real location of a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K26b0.png), a[2], and a[3]. It based on my code they should be at `'0x3f7cc10' + "index_offset"`.

Is there an easy way of getting this or is it rather contrived?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want this? Python does not really expose this kind of information, and you shouldn't need it.

Comment: The location of the list is not the same as the location of the array it uses. Lists are more than just arrays, they just use arrays internally.

Comment: I am teaching this subject and i want to show how things are stored. I am fairly new. I know Python does not really tell you this detail

Comment: @L3viathan thats why i have "arrays" in quotes in my post. I am trying to track down the website that showed how python stores the memory.

Comment: Well I think you are taking the wrong approach. If you want to teach Python programming, don't worry about memory locations. If you want to teach memory management, use a low-level language like C.

Comment: @DanielRoseman question still stands. Is there any way of doing this? easy or contrived? This is also something that I am somewhat interested in myself. I know Python programmers don't need to know it. Doesn't mean we can't. Or any article online that explains this that you know of? I know that using NumPy uses a different way of storing Lists/arrays that is more like Java

Comment: Speaking of C, here's the [CPython implementation of a list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c).  Maybe you could write a C extension for Python that allows you to expose these pointers?  I think you'd be better off just drawing it out on a whiteboard than actually finding the addresses in memory.